# How can i fix this error? ERROR TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'userdata.user')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

How can i fix this error in my project? the error is  ERROR  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'userdata.user') i am using react native expo after logging into my app and entering mainpage its giving me this error can anyone can help me to fix this error? i today send 8 hours fixing this error but i can't able to fix it can anyone can help me with that?

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { containerFull } from '../../CommonCss/pagecss'
import { formHead } from '../../CommonCss/formcss'
import Bottomnavbar from '../../Components/Bottomnavbar'
import TopNavbar from '../../Components/TopNavbar'
import FollowersRandomPost from '../../Components/FollowersRandomPost'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const Mainpage = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [userdata, setUserdata] = React.useState(null)
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
    const [city, setCity] = useState(null);
    const [data, setData] =  useState(null)
 
    useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
            .then(data => {
                // console.log('async userdata ', data)
                setUserdata(JSON.parse(data))
            })
            .catch(err => alert(err))
    }, [])

    console.log('userdata ', userdata)

  useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
            }

            let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
            setLocation(location);

            let city = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location.coords);
            setCity(city[0].city);
        })();
    }, []);


    const sendCity = () => {
        setCity(city);
        fetch('http://192.168.1.52:3000/updateCity', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                city: city,
              username: userdata.user.username
            }),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log('Success:', data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        sendCity();
    }, [])

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar />
            <TopNavbar navigation={navigation} page={"MainPage"} />
            <Bottomnavbar navigation={navigation} page={"MainPage"} />
            <FollowersRandomPost />
        </View>
    )
}

export default Mainpage

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        paddingVertical: 50,
    }
})
```

And why something city value becomes null and something new york which is correct how to fix null?

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { containerFull } from '../../CommonCss/pagecss'
import { formHead } from '../../CommonCss/formcss'
import Bottomnavbar from '../../Components/Bottomnavbar'
import TopNavbar from '../../Components/TopNavbar'
import FollowersRandomPost from '../../Components/FollowersRandomPost'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const Mainpage = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [userdata, setUserdata] = useState(null);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const [city, setCity] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] =  useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserData() {
      try {
        const userDataString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        const userData = JSON.parse(userDataString);
        setUserdata(userData);
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    }

    getUserData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getLocation() {
      try {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        }

        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setLocation(location);

        let city = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location.coords);
        setCity(city[0].city);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }

    getLocation();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function sendCity() {
      try {
        setCity(city);
        const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.52:3000/updateCity', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            city: city,
            username: userdata.user.username
          }),
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Success:', data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err);
      }
    }

    if (userdata) {
      sendCity();
    }
  }, [userdata]);

console.log(city)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar />
      <TopNavbar navigation={navigation} page={"MainPage"} />
      <Bottomnavbar navigation={navigation} page={"MainPage"} />
    </View>
  );
}


export default Mainpage
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait  AsyncStorage to finish his task before using the new data, how about using top lvl await like :

```
 useEffect(() => {
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
            .then(data => {
                // console.log('async userdata ', data)
                setUserdata(JSON.parse(data))
            })
            .catch(err => alert(err))
    }, [])

    console.log('userdata ', userdata)
```

for the 2nd question if you set city state inside the useEffect and with userdata dependency this will trigger the function when userdata state change, and since city initial state is null, and you can't immediatly get the new state from getLocation neither in sendCity, without rerender your component, i think you need to add one more condition before running the function, but this might have some side effect from the useEffect..

```
useEffect(() => { 
  async function sendCity() {
     try {
      const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.52:3000/updateCity', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          city: city,
          username: userdata.user.username
        }),
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('Success:', data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error:', err);
    }
  }
  if (userdata && city) {
    sendCity();
  }
}, [userdata, city]);
```

Comment: Can you also pls check my edited one more quation what can be the better solution of it?

Comment: i am not sure to understand your question but i update the answer just in case, there is no need for you to put setState(city) here since you already set it in getLocation, however useState are asynchronous, so you can't get immediatly the state without rerender your component.